# multiple project use different launch setting profiles .net6

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, environment, visual-studio-2022

I have 2 net6 webapi project in same solution. I'm running same time 2 web api project. But i dont see anywhere how i debug Staging or Development environment. How i can select A project debug with Staging Environment and B project debug with Development environment when run same time ?

A Project ;

```
 {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5678/",
      "sslPort": 44330
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger-ui",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ProjectA": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger-ui",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:15001/"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger-ui",
      "publishAllPorts": true
    }
  }
```

B Project;

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5678/",
      "sslPort": 44330
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger-ui",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ProjectB": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger-ui",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:15001/"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger-ui",
      "publishAllPorts": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've done a similar application to this. It follows a lesson done on Udemy that follows a guy that cerate a cms shopping cart application in c#. He created a file call View where he contains the HTML Views then create another called models with the models of the application then the user has what we call a "tempdata message" that is called upon errors.

If you can try and find that video called CMSShopping cart  in c# .net on Udemy. The instructor does a similar application with models and views well constricted and you are sure to learn form those lessons.

Follow this link to view those lessons:
https://www.udemy.com/course/aspnet-mvc-5-project-cms-and-shopping-cart-with-paypal/

Comment: Can you include the pertinent information from the course that could help to answer the OP's question. The course you linked to is not free and currently costs £15.99